# How to select and compute one particular line of value from a CSV file input in java

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I wrote one program to read input from CSV file and i it was successful. But i need to select one particular line and i want to subtract one value from an another line. What should i do for processing one line.
This is the code i wrote

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Readline {
private static String slide;
private static Iterable<String[]> rows;

/**
* @param args
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
String fileName = "C:/Users/USER/Documents/SOES - Input.csv";

ArrayList<Integer> margins = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader br;
String line, token = null;
int i;
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",\"");
            i = 0;
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                token = st.nextToken();
                if (margins.size() <= i) {
                    margins.add((Integer) token.length());
                } else {
                    margins.set(
                            i,
                            Math.max(margins.get(i),
                                    (Integer) token.length()));
                }
                i++;
            }
        }

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",\"");
            i = 0;
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                token = st.nextToken();
                System.out.print(token);
                for (int j = 0; j < margins.get(i) - token.length(); j++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print("|");
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println();




        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
   catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    }
```

The output i got is

```
 Stock Id|Side|Company|Quantity|
 --------|----|-------|--------|
 1       |Buy |ABC    |10      |
 --------|----|-------|--------|
 2       |Sell|XYZ    |15      |
 --------|----|-------|--------|
 3       |Sell|ABC    |13      |
 --------|----|-------|--------|
 4       |Buy |XYZ    |10      |
 --------|----|-------|--------|
 5       |Buy |XYZ    |8       |
```

The task is i have to subtract quantity of buy of abc from quantity of sell of abc
can anyone help me ...??

Comment: Do you want to store only after subtracting? What is your desired result? Give some samples.

Comment: Stock Id,Side,Company,Quantity
1,Buy,ABC,10,0,Closed
2,Sell,XYZ,15,0,Closed
3,Sell,ABC,13,3,Open
4,Buy,XYZ,10,0,Closed
5,Buy,XYZ,8,3,Open

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using `StringTokenizer` is a good choice here since a .csv file values usually separated by comma. So you may simply parse each line as an array and check necessary values:

```
ArrayList<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
...
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    rows.add(line.split(","));
...
```

Once you've got your rows, iterate through each row, get 2nd element - it's name, get 1st - side and 3rd is quantity:

```
int totalQuantity = 0;
for (String[] row : rows)
{
    if (row[2].equals("ABC))
    {
         if (row[1].equals("Sell"))
         {
              totalQuantity -= Integer.parseInt(row[3]);
         } 
         else 
         {
              totalQuantity += Integer.parseInt(row[3]);
         }
    }
}
```